# Formatting an SQL timestamp with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

I have a mySQL database with a timestamp field. It currently only has one entry while I'm testing, it is

```
2010-02-20 13:14:09
```

I am pulling from the database and using

```
echo date("m-d-Y",$r['newsDate'])
```

My end result is showing as

```
12-31-69
```

Anyone know why?

Edit:
editedit:
disregard that edit... the FTP addon for notepad++ timed out and unfortunately doesn't display an error when it can't synch.

Comment: Ah... did not realize that mySQL was UNIX time coded... that makes sense, then.

Comment: If `$r['timestamp']` is empty you're going to get whatever time the system uses as the starting point for epoch time. (Which usually is 01-01-70 or 12-31-69)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The [`date`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function expects an [UNIX timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) as its second parameter -- which means you have to convert the date you get from the DB to an UNIX timestamp, which can be done using [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/strtotime) :

```
$db = '2010-02-20 13:14:09';
$timestamp = strtotime($db);
echo date("m-d-Y", $timestamp);
```

And you'll get :

```
02-20-2010
```

You were passing the `'2010-02-20 13:14:09'` string to the `date` function ; that string is not a valid UNIX Timestamp.

`'12-31-69`' is probably `1970-01-01`, in your locale ; and `1970-01-01` is the Epoch -- the date that corresponds to the 0 UNIX Timestamp.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted - it is correct. You can use the strtotime php function or the UNIX_TIMESTAMP SQL method as suggested by Urda

Comment: @Simon : I was wondering, too, actually ;; I guessed I didn't answer the question correctly, and was wondering what was the "correct way of understanding it" ^^ ;; Thanks for your note :-)

Comment: What if i want to display the time too?

Comment: you can use something like `date("G:i", $timestamp)` - for more information see the manual http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php

Answer (score 4):

For starters, the php `date()` function is expecting seconds as the second variable. So that accounts for why your date is displaying wrong. Check this [source](http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/how-to-process-mysql-timestamp-in-php/) on that issue.

Which then provides us the answer to the problem, to get PHP to format the date from a SQL timestamp correctly, we just change the query a tad...

```
SELECT author, `when`
```

Change it to...

```
SELECT author, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`when`)
```

Then use the PHP date function, with the variable that is storing the result of that above SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use MySQL's [date_format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function instead:

```
SELECT date_format(timestampfield, '%m-%d-%Y') FROM table etc....
```

This will save you having to round-trip your timestamp into unix time and then back into a normal date string in PHP. One datetime formatting call rather than two.

Answer (score 1):

i think this will be useful to newble:

example basic subtraction 1 hour from date from MYSQL format:

```
$to='2013-25-10 22:56:00'; //curr time
$timestamp = strtotime($to); //convert to Unix timestamp
$timestamp = $timestamp-3600; //subtract 1 hour (3600 this is 1 hour in seconds)
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$timestamp); //show new date
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: After checking, it appears that MySQL returns a `timestamp` as a string to PHP, so this answer was bogus :)

Anyway, the reason you get a date in 1969 is probably that you're converting a zero unix time from UTC to localtime.  The unix time is the number of seconds since 1970.  So a value of 0 means 1970.  You probaby live in a timezone with a negative offset, like GMT-6, which ends up being 31-12-69.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I was wrestling with this for a week (longer but i took a break from it).

I have two specific fields in tables

```
creationDate > timestamp > current_timestamp
editDate > timestamp > current_timestamp
```

they were pulling out either dec 31 1969, or just nothing... annoying... very annoying

in mysql query i did:

```
            unix_timestamp(creationDate) AS creationDate
            unix_timestamp(editDate) AS editDate
```

in php convert i did:

```
    $timestamp = $result_ar['creationDate'];
    $creationDate = date("Y-M-d (g:i:s a)", $timestamp)
            echo($creationDate);

    $editstamp = $result_ar['editDate'];
    $editDate = date("Y-M-d (g:i:s a)", $editstamp)
            echo($editDate);
```

this solved my problem for me returning

```
            2010-Jun-28 (5:33:39 pm)
            2010-Jun-28 (12:09:46 pm)
```

respectively.

I hope this helps someone out..