# time() function mathematics

Tags: php, math

I'm using time() to store date in the database.
I have some kind of advertising web site.
Users submit their ads and number of the days they want their ads to be shown for example:

> title    : ad title....
>
> duration : 20 days
>
> creation date : time() (I get the creation date by time() when I'm
>   submitting this ad on the  database. )

I need to calculate expiration date for each ad on epoch format.

```
exp_date = creation date + 20 days ; /// this line is hypothetical , i need correct way to calculate exp_Date
sql->set(experation date = exp_date);
```

Also I need to know how much time is left to the exp date in days and hours and minutes and show it on the page.

```
    $current time = time();
    $remaining_time = $current time - $exp date ; //this line is hypothetical , i need correct way to calculate remaining_time
    echo 'remaining time : '.$remaining_time ;
```

At last I don't want to show expired ads (I'm not sure the best way to do this is to calculate time when I'm showing the ads maybe I could somehow automatically disable ads status after 20 days?)

```
    current date = time();
    if (ads experation date > current date ) // this line is hypothetical , i need to calculate this 
    sql->update ('set ads status= 0');
    echo 'this ad has been expires ';
    exit;
```

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233692/php-add-time-to-time

Comment: @Max, if you want a correct answer, I can advice you to edit your question. Its not clear what you want, and your code samples are not right (missing curly braces, identifiers with whitespace).

Comment: they are not really sample codes just some explanation , i edit them  anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the expiration date:

```
$expiration = time() + 1728000; // 1728000 = 20 * 24 * 60 * 60 (20 days)
```

To calculate the time left, you should do something like

```
$currentTime = time();
$seconds = $expiration - $currentTime;

$daysLeft = (int)($seconds / 86400); // 86400 = 24*60*60 (seconds in one day)
$seconds -= $daysLeft * 86400;
$hoursLeft = (int)($seconds / 3600); // 3600 = 60*60 (seconds in one hour)
$seconds -= $hoursLeft * 3600;
$minutesLeft = (int)($seconds / 60); // seconds in one minute
$seconds -= $minutesLeft * 60;
```

`$daysLeft`, `$hoursLeft`, `$minutesLeft` and `$seconds` are the values that you want

Answer (score 0):

> I need to calculate expiration date for each ad on epoch format.

Do you happen to know how the number of seconds in one minute? What about minutes in hour? Hours in a day?
what makes you unable to multiply these numbers?

> I don't want to show expired ads

don't show them. this is what SQL for. `WHERE exp_date > unix_timestamp()` will select only actual ads.

Answer (score -1):

Why not make life simple by running a script once a day (`cron` will do this) and do through those ads an delete (or move) them?