# How can i take sql current timestamp and output as php date()?

Tags: php, sql, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formating an SQL timestamp with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303724/formating-an-sql-timestamp-with-php)

I have a column in my SQL table that has default current timestamp values. I am trying to output it in a more readable format using `date()`.

However, no matter which format I use, I always get the same date: `1970-01-01 00:33:32`

Here is an example value of the current timestamp from the DB: `2012-08-09 06:37:58`

Below is the code I use to try to "convert" it to a readable format:

```
$value['current_date']// is the var from the database.(containing 2012-08-09 06:37:58)
$somevar = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value['current_date']);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for everyone else who helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the wrong value in the second parameter. The [date() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) expects a UNIX-style timestamp as the second parameter, not a string representation of a date. Use the [strtotime() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to correct this:

```
$somevar = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($value['current_date']));
```

As someone else pointed out, however, why are you bothering to do this formatting? The format style you want is already in the database. It should be as easy as:

```
echo $value['current_date'];
```

Comment: Jonah Thanks for the help, does TIMESTEMP - current timestemp as a default doesn't use UNIX style ?

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` is a MySQL type; it has (essentially) no correlation to the types present in PHP. The `strtotime` function will convert the TIMESTAMP value (essentially a string), to the UNIX-timestamp (integer) equivalent.

Comment: jonah your idea seemed to work

Comment: Great! I'm glad to help out. Remember to mark the answer as accepted, to help others in the future who stumble upon this question.

Comment: Wouldn't forget. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Why formatting the timestamp if it already exists in the desired format?

Regarding the actual problem:

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

`date()` only accepts unix timestamps (seconds since 1970-1-1 00:00:00 UTC) or no timestamp at all. if you want to work with a timestamp like you have you need to create an unix timestamp first with `date_create()`, `mktime` , or `strtotime`

Comment: Leon That was just a test i thought of using something safe after all the tries I've made.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are having is because the second argument of the `date()` should be a timestamp, and since you are passing the raw string containing `2012-08-09 06:37:58`, php does not know what to make of it.

Modify your code as below and it should work:

```
$somevar = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($value['current_date']));
```

You can now use any date formats in place of `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` as you wish